Get size of http.Request
In my application, I would like to register how many bytes are transferred down the wire by my HTTP client, to keep this metric under control.
I could not find a way to accomplish this easily. The http.Request objects have a convenient method Write which fills a buffer with the HTTP packet that would travel over the network, but if I call this then the body gets close, and calling http.Client.Do on this request does not send the right packet. Cloning the request did not help.
So here is my question: how can I obtain the size (in bytes) of the request I'm about to send (or that I just sent)? Is it possible to do this also for HTTPS connections?

You can wrap the body stream with a counting reader. That will capture the body length as you submit them.

To monitor the size of the request being sent or already sent, you can create a custom implementation of http.RoundTripper that intercepts the request and response and calculates the size. Please check example code:
import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
)

type SizeTrackingTransport struct {
    Transport http.RoundTripper
}

func (t *SizeTrackingTransport) RoundTrip(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error) {
    // Capture request body
    var requestBody bytes.Buffer
    if req.Body != nil {
        _, err := io.Copy(&requestBody, req.Body)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    }

    // Create a clone of the request to send it later
    clonedReq := req.Clone(req.Context())
    clonedReq.Body = io.NopCloser(&requestBody)

    // Send the cloned request using the provided Transport
    resp, err := t.Transport.RoundTrip(clonedReq)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    // Capture response body
    var responseBody bytes.Buffer
    if resp.Body != nil {
        _, err := io.Copy(&responseBody, resp.Body)
        if err != nil {
            return nil, err
        }
    }

    // Calculate and print request and response sizes
    fmt.Printf("Request size: %d bytes\n", requestBody.Len())
    fmt.Printf("Response size: %d bytes\n", responseBody.Len())

    // Replace the original response body with the captured one
    resp.Body = io.NopCloser(&responseBody)

    return resp, nil
}

func main() {
    // Create a custom HTTP client with the SizeTrackingTransport
    client := &http.Client{
        Transport: &SizeTrackingTransport{
            Transport: http.DefaultTransport,
        },
    }

    // Example request
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "https://example.com", nil)

    // Send the request using the custom client
    _, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error:", err)
        return
    }
}

This code only provides a basic implementation. Depending on your needs, you may want to refine it. I hope this will help

Thanks for the answer. This implementation gives me the length of the body accurately. However, I need to know the size of the entire request, including the headers. Is there a way to accomplish that?

I think we can utilize ContentLength of requests if you write using the types *bytes.Buffer, *bytes.Reader, or *strings.Reader
Content length is one of the HTTP headers, for size of the message body

The Content-Length header indicates the size of the message body, in bytes, sent to the recipient.

And Golang document net/http said

If body is of type *bytes.Buffer, *bytes.Reader, or *strings.Reader, the returned request's ContentLength is set to its exact value (instead of -1), GetBody is populated (so 307 and 308 redirects can replay the body), and Body is set to NoBody if the ContentLength is 0.

For example, you can test it using this code.
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "net/http/httptest"
)

func main() {
    testServer := httptest.NewServer(http.HandlerFunc(func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    }))
    defer testServer.Close()

    reqBody := bytes.NewBufferString(`TEST`)
    req, _ := http.NewRequest("POST", testServer.URL, reqBody)
    fmt.Printf("Request body length is %d\n", req.ContentLength)
}


Then it shows the below. You can run it on Go playground https://go.dev/play/p/Bei0x9v7Bbc
Request body length is 4

